# How do I run the javascript APIs multiple times?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to run a javascript API extraction multiple times to no avail. Here is what I have, but it returns the same values in the list I made. I am trying to iterate between the pages of the API call.

```
const https = require('https');
ids = []

for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
   options = {
       hostname: 'api.intercom.io',
       port: 443,
       path: '/conversations?per_page=10page=' + i + "",
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
           "Accept": "application/json",
           "Authorization": "XXXX"
       } // add headers here

   };

   req = https.request(options, (res) => {
       console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
       console.log('headers:', res.headers);

       res.on('data', (data) => {
           var d = JSON.parse(data);
           len = d.conversations.length
           for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
               ids.push(d.conversations[i].id)
           }
           console.log(ids)
       });
   });

   req.on('error', (e) => {
       console.error(e);
   });

   req.end();
}
```

Comment: This may be totally wrong, but try throwing a "let req =" on the first req in your block and see if that helps. I think you may have a global variable issue there which is breaking your ".on"s

Comment: I made an experiment with your code. Without global variable, it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resetting `i` in your interior `for` loop. Just use another iterator there:

```
for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
   ids.push(d.conversations[i].id)
}
```

Comment: Realized that, but that did not fix the issue